# Create a MS Access query in DB with circular relationships

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a database with a circular relationship (correct terminology?) between its tables. The following diagram shows these relationships:

[image]

**Question: How do I create a query that produces the output below.**

As you can see, each team has a type (large or small) each of which has a specific set of roles/positions; also, each person fills a role, and each person is a member of a team.

[image: Desired Result]

The query should list every role for each of the two teams even if the role is currently unfilled. (*Notice Team A is missing one member, and Team B is missing two members.*)

Everything I've tried only shows roles that are currently being filled by someone on the team -- the unfilled roles on a team are hidden. Part of the motivation for this query is that I want to be able to identify unfilled positions and overall headcount by team.

**EDIT:** To clarify, this is not homework; this simplified version of the database with which I am working. In this example, the TeamTypes table contains a canonical list of team types (e.g. small, medium, large). The roles available on each team depend on the team type, e.g. a small team has a Team Lead, an Admin Assistant, and several Members positions/roles while a large team has more members plus 2 deputy team leads. The 'LnkTeamTypeRoles' table links (i.e. defines) how the roles and the team types are related.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing an inner join between Roles and Personnel.  It will need to be a left join if a role is not always filled.  I would write it like this.

```
select t.Designation Team, tt.TeamType TeamType, r.Role, isnull(ltrim(rtrim(p.LastName)) + ', ' + p.FirstName, 'unfilled') Personnel
from Teams t join TeamTypes tt on t.TeamTypeId = tt.ID
join LnkTeamTypeRoles lttr on tt.ID = lttr.TeamTypeId
join Roles r on lttr.RoleID = r.ID
left join Personnel p on t.ID = p.TeamId and r.ID = p.RoleId
```

Result Set:

```
Team    TeamType    Role            Personnel
TeamA   Large       Lead            Mikel, James                    
TeamA   Large       Admin Assitant  Everitt, Rhonda                   
TeamA   Large       Member          unfilled
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I make two assumptions.

- I assume **LnkTeamType** is the list of canonical roles for a team type.  If every team should have all a member for every role, the a canonical list is unnecessary.
- I assume this is homework, so I won't provide SQL.

> correct terminology

No.  There's nothing circular about it, except for the picture.  It just so happens that there are two FK relationships to **TeamTypes** and **Roles**.  That doesn't affect your query.

> query that produces the output below

First, you need the canonical pairs of **TeamType** and **Role** ("every role for every team").  If that's in **LnkTeamType**, start there.  If not,

```
from TeamType cross join Roles
```

produces a Cartesian product of *roles x teams*.  Then join to **Teams** to get Team IDs.

Finally,

```
outer join Personnel as p on Teams.Id = p.Teamid
```

An *outer join* differs from a regular join ("inner join") in that the product includes unmatched rows.  *Outer* here may be thought of in terms sets: the keys -- or, at any rate, the join criteria -- in the *inner* table constitute a subset of those in the *outer* table.   In a Venn diagram, the inner table would lie completely within the outer one.  People often refer to the outer table as the "preserved" table, because none of its rows are dropped.  In SQL syntax, the outer table appears to the left of the words `outer join`.

To sum up, we have one of these two:

- outer-join( join( join( join( LnkTeamType, TeamTypes), Roles), Teams ), Personell)
- outer-join( join( cross-join( Roles, TeamTypes ), Teams ), Personell)

I hope that gives you the information you need to write your query.

Comment: @onedaywhen I think Cartesian Product is a pretty common term when talking about SQL and not really something only someone with a background in mathematics would get. Using "product" in both Cartesian Product and product being the result of a join is correct in both instances (both in the multiplication sense and where product ~ a result sense).

Comment: Access SQL does not support the `CROSS JOIN` or `OUTER JOIN` syntax. The examples you give won't work unless modified.

Comment: @James -1: you didn't answer my questions so I assume you are simply using mathematical terms inappropriately in a database context.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Outer Join`  between `Personnel` and `Roles` table

Comment: Access doesn't support `OUTER JOIN`. I think you mean `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Ah, yes please. LEFT JOIN